# Python argparse module usage

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have a program which is called like this:

```
program.py add|remove|show
```

The problem here is that depending on the add/remove/show command it takes a variable number of arguments, just like this:

```
program.py add "a string" "another string"
program.py remove "a string"
program.py show
```

So, 'add' command would take 2 string arguments, while 'remove' command would take 1 only argument and 'show' command wouldn't take any argument.
I know how to make a basic argument parser using the module argparse, but I don't have much experience with it, so I started from this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("command", choices=["add", "remove", "show"])
```

But I don't know how to continue and how to implement this functionality depending on the command. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for argparse's subparsers...

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "add" command
parser_add = subparsers.add_parser('add', help='add help')
# [example] add an argument to a specific subparser
parser_add.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')

# create the parser for the "remove" command
parser_remove = subparsers.add_parser('remove', help='remove help')

# create the parser for the "show" command
parser_show = subparsers.add_parser('show', help='show help')
```

This example code is stolen with very little modification from the language [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers).

Comment: How do I check which option has been chosen and get the correspondent variables?

Comment: @xBlackout -- the documentation I linked gives advice on that too ... Search the page for a sentence that starts with "One particularly effective way of handling sub-commands".  The tl;dr; is that you can use `set_defaults` to attach a function to the namespace based on which subparser was selected.  Then you just call that function to execute the actions associated with the selected subparser.